# CSS transition not working with transform

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following CSS:

```css
.popup {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  z-index: 1001;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.centered {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hidden {
  top:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  top: 50%;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to perform an animation `bottom->top` when a popup get's visible and `top->bottom` when it get's hidden.

Before, I was using `transition: all 1s ease;` and it was working, but it was laggy so I decided to use `transition: transform 1s ease;`. Doing this  the transition is not working anymore even if I think the code should be fine. Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Here a working CodePen example:

http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/QyeJjq

And here is a not working example:

http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/KVOrgQ

They are exactly the same, except for `transition: transform 1s ease;` instead of `transition: all 1s ease;

Comment: Just a little thing, `-ms-transition` does not exist ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously when you had `transition: all 1s ease`, in that translate and top values were getting animated.
But once you changed it to `transition: transform 1s ease` `top` property was left out.

```
 .popup {
      background-color: white;
      border-style: solid;
      z-index: 1001;
      box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
      border-radius: 3px;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease; 
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease;
      /* edited the line below by adding top also*/
      transition: transform 1s ease, top 1s ease;
    }

    .centered {
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .hidden {
      top: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    .visible {
      top: 50%;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In the working example you're transitioning `all` the properties and not only the `transform` property: this is important because also the `top` property is involved in the effect, changing from `100%` to `50%` (when you remove the class `hidden` and add the class `visible`).

As you can verify, if you change

```
transition: transform 1s ease;
```

into

```
transition: transform 1s ease, top 1s ease;
```

the transition works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this pen](http://codepen.io/thekirankumardash/pen/mVNQMr).

CSS: Modify your css to the following

```
.popup {
  ...
  transition: transform 1s ease, top 1s ease;
}
```

And also do not use a vendor prefix if it is not necessary.
For transition only `-webkit` is needed. and for transform `-ms` and `-webkit` will do the job.

Comment: Please change `transition: transition 1s ease, top 1s ease;` to `transition: transform 1s ease, top 1s ease;`